# Number of loops in Numpy Element wise operation

Tags: python, numpy

I am taking element wise power of a numpy array as well as a python list. Why are there 10000 loops for the numpy operation?

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(1000)

In [2]: %timeit a**5
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.8 µs per loop

In [3]: b = range(1000)

In [4]: %timeit [i**5 for i in b]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 ms per loop
```

Comment: When you use `timeit` magic, the output shows `%d loops`, refeering to the number of times that instruction was launched in 1sec, which measures the speed of the method as in `N times per second`. Those are not *real* loops.

Comment: Because each iteration takes 10x less time, so the numpy timeit can complete 10x more iterations in roughly the same amount of time.

Comment: You can specify the number of loops with the `-n` argument, `%timeit -n100 np.arange(1000)**5`.  Without it, it choose a larger N for faster calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface):

> If -n is not given, a suitable number of loops is calculated by trying
>   successive powers of 10 until the total time is at least 0.2 seconds.

In other words, timeit runs your statement 10000 times because that's about how many it can do in .2 seconds. It has nothing to do with the number you passed to `arange`.

Comment: although if you pass a big enough list in you might have a smaller `n` value